# How to preconfigure the Cygwin installation?

Tags: windows, cygwin

I would like to help my colleagues to install Cygwin properly.

We have a full network copy of the Cygwin repository along with the `setup.exe`.

How can I preconfigure the packages I want to install with Cygwin (auto check the packages to install)?

Next, how can I preconfigure some files (such as `/etc/...` configuration files) after installation?

I am thinking to write a BATCH script that calls `setup.exe` with command-line arguments but I think there is a better solution.

When I try using `setup.exe` from the command line I get a weird error related to McAfee but I don't have McAfee installed on my computer.

```
c:\Cygwin_root>setup.exe -q -L -l . -X -R "C:\cygwin" -P check

c:\Cygwin_root>Starting cygwin install, version 2.774
User has backup/restore rights
io_stream_cygfile: fopen(/etc/setup/net-proxy-host) failed 2 No such file or directory
io_stream_cygfile: fopen(/etc/setup/net-proxy-port) failed 2 No such file or directory
io_stream_cygfile: fopen(/etc/setup/extrakeys) failed 2 No such file or directory
Current Directory: .
Could not open service McShield for query, start and stop. McAfee may not be installed, or we don't have access.
root: C:\cygwin binary system
Selected local directory: .
mbox fatal: Fatal Error: Uncaught Exception
Thread: ini
Type: St13runtime_error
Message: IniParseFindVisitor: failed to open ini file, which should never happen
unattended_mode is set at mbox: returning default value
Ending cygwin install
setup.exe -q -L -l cygwin -X -R "C:\cygwin" -P check
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, You've specified the -l option but didn't provide a path.  So when the installer looks for the ini file of packages, it cannot.  I don't think this is McAfee related.  Rather, have you tried specifying the local path?